# python: sorting large datasets to use in transform_scalar function to plot data on the map

Tags: sorting, python-2.7, plot

I am trying to plot a large dataset on the map and as I understand, I need to use this function:

m.transform_scalar(temp, lons, lats,nx,ny)

temp is the temperature which I want to plot it on the map with lons and lats as longtitude and latitude.

here is the code:

```
m = Basemap(llcrnrlon=-145.5,llcrnrlat=1.,urcrnrlon=-2.566,urcrnrlat=46.352,\
        rsphere=(6378137.00,6356752.3142),\
        resolution='l',area_thresh=1000.,projection='lcc',\
        lat_1=50.,lon_0=-107.,ax=ax)
nx = int((m.xmax-m.xmin)/5000.)+1 
ny = int((m.ymax-m.ymin)/5000.)+1
temp3 = m.transform_scalar(temp, lons, lats,nx,ny)
```

this is the error: 
if min(delon) < 0. or min(delat) < 0.:
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I tried in different ways to sort lons and lats to cover this error, but it is still continue in different kinds of errors and I am so confused!!I don't know how to sort these large data-sets!!? Is there any other way to plot data on the map in the python? how I can challenge with this error?

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs to me because I didn't put the right lons and lats. They should be rank-1 array as the documentation indicates, instead of 2D array (meshgrid-array). If you stick with imshow, you can define lons and lats before using transform_scalar(). For example, data is a lat/lon gridded variable:

```
ny, nx = (data.shape[0], data.shape[1])
lons = np.linspace(lon_0, lon_1, nx)
lats = np.linspace(lat_0, lat_1, ny)
plotdata = m.transform_scalar(data, lons, lats, nx, ny)
im = m.imshow(plotdata, vmin = x0, vmax = x1, cmap = plt.cm.jet)
cb = m.colorbar(im)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.